# UITableViewCells are flickering when tableview first loads

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So I have a UITabelView using custom UITableViewCells. I chased down the issue and its in this method "`controllerDidChangeContent`", which is getting called about 5 times as the table loads. This method is being called because of Core Data updates.

I can stop the flickering from happening if I comment out either line that has <--- pointing at it. I am sure we do NOT want to comment out the `[self reloadData]` as that refreshes the data when Core Data is changed. But I am not so sure if `endUpdates` is ok to comment out?

```
- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
{
  [[self tableView] endUpdates]; <--
  [[self tableView] reloadData]; <-- 
  [UIView dismissIndicator];
}
```

However, if I comment out the `endUpdates` line then all the table data is NOT getting written to the UITableView. There is a couple cells missing.

I am thinking the issue isn't this method or its inner methods, but rather how the cell content is being drawn?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not need to call `reloadData` after the `endUpdates`. You make changes to your `UITableView` data source within the `beginUpdates` `endUpdates` block so that you don't have to call `reloadData`. You call `reloadData` if your entire data source has changed because it can be relatively expensive call. Using `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` gives you the ability to change/insert/delete an item from your data source without reloading the entire `UITableView`.

Here is what it should look like [(taken from Ray Wenderlich tutorial)](http://www.raywenderlich.com/999/core-data-tutorial-for-ios-how-to-use-nsfetchedresultscontroller):

```
- (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller is about to start sending change notifications, so prepare the table view for updates.
    [self.tableView beginUpdates];
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath {

    UITableView *tableView = self.tableView;

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
            [self configureCell:[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] atIndexPath:indexPath];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
           [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray
arrayWithObject:newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
           break;
    }
}


- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeSection:(id )sectionInfo atIndex:(NSUInteger)sectionIndex forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type {

    switch(type) {

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
            [self.tableView insertSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;

        case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
            [self.tableView deleteSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:sectionIndex] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
            break;
    }
}


- (void)controllerDidChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller {
    // The fetch controller has sent all current change notifications, so tell the table view to process all updates.
    [self.tableView endUpdates];
}
```

If this does not help solve your problem then I will need to see more code, specifically where you are performing the data source updates within the `beginUpdates` and `endUpdates` block.

Comment: But when I take the reloadData out of the controllerDidChangeContent when adding a new cell it adds an extra blank cell.

Comment: There were some other issues that were causing the flickering but this code is the correct way to do this.

Comment: hey jdog, what was issue that was causing flickering. Could you please tell here?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply call reloadSections method instead of [self.tableView reloadData];

```
[self.tableView reloadSections:[NSIndexSet indexSetWithIndex:0] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```